# How to use package "karnaugh-map" on Overleaf with Greek Language

Tags: babel, karnaugh

I was trying to make a Karnaugh map for an assignment and I came across this package: https://ctan.org/pkg/karnaugh-map

I tried to use it in Overleaf where I write my LaTeX code with one of the examples given in the documentation and I got this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{karnaugh-map}
\begin{document}
\begin{karnaugh-map}[4][2][1][$ab$][$c$]
\maxterms{0,2,4,5,6}
\minterms{3}
\terms{1}{$d$}
\terms{7}{$d'$}
\implicant{1}{3}
\implicant{3}{7}
\end{karnaugh-map}
\end{document}
```

Why is that happening? Do I have to do something else?

Edit: I found out why it is happening, it's because I'm using the following packages in order to type in Greek.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
```

Producing this error message

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.7 \maxterms
             {0,2,4,5,6}
?
```

How can I maybe fix it?

Comment: it's almost impossible to debug  code shown as an inage. Please make a small complete document that shows the problem and add to your question as a text block

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i think i found the problem, it is because im using this to be able to type in greek

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

Comment: Thanks for adding the example I edited it so the example is the version with the error, that makes it easier to debug.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! Sorry if my initial question was badly written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Babel Greek redefines `\&` in a way that the package does not like, you can save the original definition and restore it globally (if you do not need `\&` in a Greek section) or locally before starting the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\let\savedamp\&
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\usepackage{karnaugh-map}

\begin{document}

\let\&\savedamp
\begin{karnaugh-map}[4][2][1][$ab$][$c$]
\maxterms{0,2,4,5,6}
\minterms{3}
\terms{1}{$d$}
\terms{7}{$d'$}
\implicant{1}{3}
\implicant{3}{7}
\end{karnaugh-map}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yup this fixed my problem, thank you very much!

Comment: `\AtBeginEnvironment{karnaugh-map}{\chardef\&="26 }`

Comment: @egreg yes  haven't had time to look but I'm not sure where it needs that, tikz matrix of nodes doesn't break with the \protect as far as I can see

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess that the matrix contents is expanded somewhere, but *before* `ampersand replacement=\&` takes place. Any non `\relax` unexpandable primitive would be good as well, such as `\let\&=\vfuzz`.

Comment: @egreg yes being non expandable is the main thing, not the definition. I suspect a rogue `\edef` somewhere:-)